# Möbius function - understanding of relations

Tags: relations, order-theory, mobius-function

I am trying to understand Möbius function from the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra#Special_elements) (and also few others that I have come across so far). This function is defined in posets and so the relations in Special elements section of the wikipedia article confuse me. So what do relations $=$, $\leq$, $<$ mean in this section? Do these have the traditional meaning or does these relations mean something different?

Comment: At first $= $ is as usual and $< $ is any partial ordering on a set such that an element has finitely many $<$ and "$1$" is $<$ to every other element. Then $\mu(d,n)$ is the function such that $g(n) = \sum_{d \le n} f(d) \implies f(n) =  \sum_{d \le n} g(d)\mu(d,n) $. When $<$ is the partial order on $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$ defined by $d \le n$ if $d |n$ then $\mu(d,n) = (-1)^m$ if $n/d$ is a product of $m$ distinct primes, $\mu(d,n) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: I think it is pretty clearly written [here](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~lsoicher/designtheory.org/library/encyc/topics/posets.pdf), at page 6. So $\leq$ is the relation of poset, $<$ means strong inequality as we know it from primary school.

Comment: No, they would never use $\leq$ and $\le$ to refer to different orderings. One is strict and the other one isn't, but otherwise they are the same.

Comment: I haven't looked, but it's possible there are some spots where it's ambiguous, where you're expected to know that it's the ordinary ordering because it's referring to something like an index, something that isn't supposed to be an element of the poset.

Answer (score 1):

In the original number-theoretic case, $\leq$ would be replaced by $\mid$. The integers are partially ordered by divisibility and the Mobius function is the inverse of the zeta function, using the language of the general poset case.

Comment: Your answer did not help me. Probably I did not completely get it. Can you expand your answer, please?